# What monitoring solution should I use for Kubernetes?

Tags: linux, open-source, monitoring, server

I understand that monitoring Kubernetes is unlike other technologies.  I am familiar with Nagios.  I prefer open source solutions.  I have minimal knowledge of Zabbix, Solar Winds, Graphite, Grafana, and Prometheus.  I am curious which one has all-purpose features (as there are other things I'd like to monitor).  But my main concern is that it will be good for monitoring Kubernetes.